# Hadoop Map Task Fails When Using Compression In 2 Node Cluster. But Both Node Works Fine When Running as Single Node

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, compression

**Node1 :** `hadoop2.5.2 RedhatLinux.el6 64bit`
             build 64bit native library and it's working

**Node2 :** `hadoop2.5.2 RedhatLinux.el5 32bit`
            build 32bit native library and it's working

when running map reduce task as single node it works(with compression)

as multinode also it's working (without compression)

but as multinode with compression it's not working....

map task only finishing in one of the node(somtimes in node1, sometime in node2) in other node it is failed with error and job got failed.

> Error: java.io.IOException: Spill failed at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.checkSpillException(MapTask.java:1535)
>   at  . . Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native lz4 library not
>   available at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.Lz4Codec.getCompressorType(Lz4Codec.java:124)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool.getCompressor(CodecPool.java:148)
>   at

i tried

```
<name>mapreduce.admin.user.env</name>
 <value>LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native</value>
```

in **mapred-site.xml**
but still not working...

please suggest a solution...

Answer (score 1):

Adding these properties in **mapred-site.xml** of the Hadoop node, in which the job is submitting solved the problem.

```
    <property>
            <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.admin.user.env</name>
            <value>LD_LIBRARY_PATH={{HADOOP_COMMON_HOME}}/lib/native</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
            <value>LD_LIBRARY_PATH={{HADOOP_COMMON_HOME}}/lib/native</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.admin.user.env</name>
            <value>LD_LIBRARY_PATH={{HADOOP_COMMON_HOME}}/lib/native</value>
    </property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable debug logs for hadoop in the machine where the exception is thrown. 
restart hadoop process, post that you should be able to figure out based on logs of `NativeCodeLoader` as why native library is not loaded.

you can use below command to verify if native libraries are loaded or not.

```
hadoop checknative -a
```

Comment: Node1 : hadoop checknative -a
2017-01-16 14:02:09,041 INFO  [main] bzip2.Bzip2Factory (Bzip2Factory.java:isNativeBzip2Loaded(70)) - Successfully loaded & initialized native-bzip2 library system-native
2017-01-16 14:02:09,049 INFO  [main] zlib.ZlibFactory (ZlibFactory.java:<clinit>(49)) - Successfully loaded & initialized native-zlib library
Native library checking:
hadoop: true /home/ruleuser/hadoop/hadoop-2.5.2/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0
zlib:   true /usr/lib/libz.so.1
snappy: true /usr/lib/libsnappy.so.1
lz4:    true revision:99
bzip2:  true /usr/lib/libbz2.so.1

Comment: in Node 2 also all native library are loaded.

it works with single node but problem coming in multinode

Comment: What is output for "hadoop checknative -a" command in both the nodes when deployed in multi node. ? are they identical.

Comment: output hadoop checknative -a in node 1

Native library checking:
hadoop: true /home/ruleuser/hadoop/hadoop-2.5.2/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0
zlib:   true /usr/lib/libz.so.1
snappy: true /usr/lib/libsnappy.so.1
lz4:    true revision:99
bzip2:  true /usr/lib/libbz2.so.1
--------------
in node 2

hadoop: true /home/admin/hadoop-2.5.2/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0
zlib:   true /lib64/libz.so.1
snappy: true /usr/lib64/libsnappy.so.1
lz4:    true revision:99
bzip2:  true /lib64/libbz2.so.1
-----------
one library is 64bit and other is 32bit

Comment: what is output in 32bit machine.

Comment: output of 32bit machine#
hadoop checknative -a
2017-01-16 16:33:55,231 INFO  [main] bzip2.Bzip2Factory (Bzip2Factory.java:isNativeBzip2Loaded(70)) - Successfully loaded & initialized native-bzip2 library system-native
2017-01-16 16:33:55,240 INFO  [main] zlib.ZlibFactory (ZlibFactory.java:<clinit>(49)) - Successfully loaded & initialized native-zlib library
Native library checking:
hadoop: true /home/ruleuser/hadoop/hadoop-2.5.2/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0
zlib:   true /usr/lib/libz.so.1
snappy: true /usr/lib/libsnappy.so.1
lz4:    true revision:99
bzip2:  true /usr/lib/libbz2.so.1

Comment: in node1 it is using jdk version 1.7(64bit) in node2 it used jdk version 1.6(32bit)